# Downloaded folders with files (as zip) don't open

Tags: lightning-web-components, js, zip

I have a little problem. I compress files in zip and download its. Everything is ok, but files (pdf, png, jpeg...) don't open.
I use this script:

```
async downloadFolder(folder) {
    const zip = new JSZip();

    async function createZipArchive(zipFolder, folderId) {
        const folderContent = await getFolderContent({ folderId });
        const files = folderContent.files;

        for (const file of files) {
            if (file.mimeType.includes("folder")) {
                const innerFolder = zipFolder.folder(file.name);
                await createZipArchive(innerFolder, file.id);
            } else {
                console.log(file.mimeType);
                const fileContent = await getFileContent({ fileId: file.id });
                
                const textEncoder = new TextEncoder();
                const encodedContent = textEncoder.encode(fileContent);


                const blob = new Blob([encodedContent], { type: file.mimeType });
                zipFolder.file(file.name, blob);
            }
        }
    }

    const rootFolder = zip.folder(folder.name);
    await createZipArchive(rootFolder, folder.id);

    const content = await zip.generateAsync({ type: 'blob' });
    const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(content);

    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = blobUrl;
    a.download = folder.name + '.zip';
    a.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
    URL.revokeObjectURL(blobUrl);
}
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also i used Uint8Array instead of TextEncoder: const byteArray = new Uint8Array(fileContent.length);
                    console.log(fileContent.length);
                    for (let i = 0; i < fileContent.length; i++) {
                        byteArray[i] = fileContent.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff;
                    }

but it also doesn`t open my files